# SignatureDoesNotMatch while uploading file from React.js using boto3 generate_presigned_url

Tags: python, reactjs, amazon-s3, boto3

Currently the presigned url is generated from Python Lambda function and testing it on postman to upload the file works perfectly.

When uploading file from **React.js** using axios it fails with 403 status code and below error.

**Code**: SignatureDoesNotMatch

**Message**: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method

**Python Code**

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
params = {
   'Bucket': 'bucket_name',
   'Key': 'unique_id.pdf',
   'ContentType': "application/pdf"
}

s3_response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod='put_object', Params=params, ExpiresIn=300)
```

**React Code**

```
const readFileDataAsBuffer = (file) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (event) => {
        
        resolve(event.target.result);
    };

    reader.onerror = (err) => {
        reject(err);
    };

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
});

const onFileUploadChange = async (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];

    const tempdata = await readFileDataAsBuffer(file);

    return axios({
        method: 'put',
        url: presigned_url_link,
        data: tempdata
    })
    .then(() => {})
    .catch(() => {});
```

};

Answer (score 0):

passing Content-Type worked for s3 link while uploading